Cannot clone GitLab repository: The requested URL returned error: 403
I am trying to clone the repository of one of our projects on GitLab but get a 403 error whenever cloning with HTTPS. It works without any problems on another laptop.
I have tried the following:

Deleted the .gitconfig file
Removed the entries for the GitLab website with the repositories from the Windows Credential Manager
Tried cloning the repository with different tools (Git Bash, VS Code, Git GUI)
Unset and reset credential.helper manager

The response is always the same and I am not prompted to enter a password. It seems like the credentials are saved somewhere and I don't seem to be able to update them.
Note: I do not want to use the SSH option (which works) because the further steps require an HTTPS connection.
Does anyone have any suggestions of how I can reset/update the credentials on my machine?
